# using crypt as a password hash and comparing values?

Tags: php, comparison, crypt

I have decided to use crypt() to encrpyt my passwords on my database using a salt, as after much research it seems the best option.

I am curious though as to why this works and gets a match:

```
$info['password'] == crypt($_POST['password'])
```

And comparing identically like this doesn't:

```
$info['password'] === crypt($_POST['password'])
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: in first statment you are `= `assigning value not comparing `==`. Is this typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://uk.php.net/crypt) explains the phenomenon you're experiencing.  The second argument documentation states:

> An optional salt string to base the hashing on. If not provided, the behaviour is defined by the algorithm implementation and can lead to unexpected results.

There's every chance you'll get 10 different values when you run the following:

```
<?php
$string = "password";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo crypt($string) . "\n";
}
```

I get the following:

```
$1$sWCzgR2e$vjR1CagStx0QbRYy/VbWm.
$1$C5TexeGI$ifWZ3mhGKthQ.ZW1UEswl/
$1$miA.EAYy$A6amxA.B4HvebndP/2ydx1
$1$izL6b3lz$hKncuA4oGv.8DAlAcybm..
$1$EqPefzSc$1XvQFf7pqFeuFz68lA1tv0
$1$njFWwWUo$NeQxtRHyUUzivVhidQSt5/
$1$LH3CVBV1$IIPPuHPUNL04ODtuRw0WR0
$1$/K75BwgK$MhSmhXtXF9Gn6ujx3YgE30
$1$OfddZpSQ$4u.dgsAWe4M/bOerUYTxr0
$1$G6JPvJpQ$aGvHluWRSy659MUe9P/aN.
```

I'd recommend using your database salt as the second argument for your `crypt($password, $salt)` call.

Answer (score -1):

the operator "==" checks to see if the two variables have the same value and the "===" operator tests to see if the variables have the same value and type:
http://nz.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

so
1 == "1" is true
1 === "1" is not true

Comment: Not really. <?
echo (1=="1"?"yes":"no");
echo (1==="1"?"yes":"no");
?>

Comment: Read the question, they are **both strings**: `<?php $var = "test"; var_dump($var == "test"); var_dump($var === "test");`